# Problem without *char (c_char) in rust function with a message not helpful

Tags: c, pointers, rust

I've built a link with my c library and the call of a specific function gives me a non-helpful error message (probably because i'm using unsafe {} decorator).

The message is:

> ./build.sh: line 7: 44630 Bus error: 10 cargo run --example
>   ferris-astro-example

and the line 7 is

```
cargo run --example ferris-astro-example
```

Until now, with this C library, I compiled without error for 2 other functions, but for the last one it doesn't work.

The code in the documentation interface of the C library is :

```
char *swe_version(char *svers);

/* svers is a string variable with sufficient space to contain the version number (255 char) */
```

The doc says:

> The function returns a pointer to the string svers, i.e. to the version number of the Swiss Ephemeris that your software
>   is using.

And that is what I have written in rust:

```
  use std::os::raw::c_char;                                                                                                                                                                 
  #[link(name = "swe")]                                                                             
  extern "C" {                                                                                      
     // ... (other function)
     pub fn swe_version(s_version: *mut c_char) -> *mut c_char;
  }
```

and then the code is called by

```
let version: *mut c_char = "\0".as_bytes().as_ptr() as *mut c_char;
unsafe {
    // ... 
    // Get the version
    raw::swe_version(version);
    // ...
    }
// ...
```

I'm sure that the error is a mistake of version because no

```
version = raw::swe_version(version)
```

**EDIT some hour later...**

I found a solution to compile without error :

```
use std::os::raw::c_uchar;
use std::ptr;
mod raw;
pub fn test_lib() {
    let version = ptr::null_mut() as *mut c_uchar;
    unsafe {
        raw::swe_version(&version);
        // Free memory
        raw::swe_close();
    }
}
```

And raw :

```
use std::os::raw::c_uchar;

#[link(name = "swe")]
extern "C" {
    // pub fn swe_test(path: *const c_char); // swe_test try
    // pub fn swe_set_ephe_path(path: *const c_uchar);
    /// Version
    pub fn swe_version(s_version: &*mut c_uchar) -> *mut c_uchar;
    /// Free memory
    pub fn swe_close();
}
```

Thank you *carton* for helping, the debugger says me the same :

```
<read memory from 0x38302e32 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)>
```

I don’t find the solution on internet/book to define an array of 255 c_uchar.

I tried cast with *mut [c_uchar] and * mut Vec without success.

But c_uchar is unsigned 0 to 255 ? (before I used c_char) and c_schar is -128 - > 128

**Edit 2**

I can't get work your code and some variations.

I'm not sure if the array [0, 255] is the good solution, this gives me an array of integer

This code works witouth break/segemant fault:

```
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::ptr;
mod raw;
pub fn test_lib() {
    let version = ptr::null_mut() as *mut [c_char; 255];
    unsafe {
        raw::swe_version(&version);
        // Free memory
        raw::swe_close();
    }
}
```

```
use std::os::raw::c_char;

#[link(name = "swe")]
extern "C" {
    /// Version
    pub fn swe_version(s_version: &*mut [c_char; 255]) -> *mut [c_char; 255];
    /// Free memory
    pub fn swe_close();
}
```

But I can't find a way to puti the variable "version" in a CStr or CString...

In debugger I have this in version after raw::swe_version(&version)

```
version: <invalid adress>
[0]: <read memory from 0x38302e32 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)>
[1]: <read memory from 0x38302e33 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)>
[2]: <read memory from 0x38302e34 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)>
[3]: <read memory from 0x38302e35 failed (0 of 1 bytes read)>
and ... the same until [255]
```

With your solution *rodrigo*

```
use std::ffi::CStr;
mod raw;
pub fn test_lib() {
    let mut version = [0; 255];
    let v = unsafe {
        let p = version.as_mut_ptr();
        raw::swe_version(p);
        CStr::from_ptr(p)
    };
}
```

I have an error on line:

> raw::swe_version(p)

With this in my editor:

> 1 src/lib.rs|13 col 26 error| mismatched types expected array of 255 elements, found integer note: expected type `*mut [i8; 255]` found type `*mut {integer}` [E0308]

Comment: The documentation of the function says you must pass it a 255 bytes string. You pass it a 1 byte string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that you need an array of 255 characters, so declare just that. And since you are going to change those chars do not forget to add `mut`:

```
let mut version = [0; 255];
```

Then you can use [`slice::as_mut_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_mut_ptr) to get the raw pointer and call the external function:

```
unsafe {
    swe_version(version.as_mut_ptr());
}
```

Being a C function, probably it will fill the array with a NUL-terminated string. If that is the case, you can get that easily using [`CStr::from_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr):

```
let mut version = [0; 255];
let version = unsafe {
    let p = version.as_mut_ptr();
    swe_version(p);
    std::ffi::CStr::from_ptr(p)
};
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! I Found the solution in my book just before (I have search for "Array" and I don't find the term because the name of french is "Tableau"). But still doesn't work for now (Still the same error but with 255 char) ! I go now test your solution

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.  i wish you a merry Xmas. Thanks for your help, the raw needs to be : pub fn swe_version(s_version: *mut c_char) -> *mut c_char; (and not an array of c_char)